# How to merge login/signup into one option

Tags: gui-design, user-behavior, usability-testing, login, signup

Currently for our platform, we are using facebook login & Mobile number verification for login and sign up pages. User does not need to have any additional password to complete his registration. So basically user's journey is same for any of the option.

Since the steps are same, we want to merge both options but cannot find any suitable example for this. Have anyone done this already? If yes, what's the customer response towards this?

Comment: "_we want to merge both options but cannot find any suitable example for this_" – Perhaps the sentence' second part is already the answer. And I too [remember/remind of Jon](https://youtu.be/IpoFzx-mClk?t=37). ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using tabs above to differentiate between the two.

[image]

[image]

in my experience using facebook login. i simply use facebook login/signup regardless without thinking too much as fb login is already widely used. The only difference between signing up vs logging in with fb login is 1 extra step when signing up where facebook asks to grant permissions.

Answer (score 0):

In general I'd recommend to be careful with trying to do something new in this area, unless it's absolutely tested and user(fool)prove. You got to be very careful about this - I see the danger of confusing and especially prospects and thus loosing them. The standard expectation of users imho is that Registration and Login are two different processes.

Can you add mockups/screenshots to clarify your question a bit?